# Why Arduino pins don't output 0 volt?

Tags: pwm, voltage

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(5, 0);
  // or
  //digitalWrite(5, LOW);
}
```

Output is 0.003V and the tiny voltage causes the circuit to draw 20uA.

Is there anyway to get absolute 0V from Arduino PWM pin?

Comment: That is a quite tiny voltage. This is not a code issue, since you cannot do more that driving the pin to LOW (which is what happens, when you use `analogWrite(pin,0)`. Please show us your circuit.

Comment: @chrisl I'm converting arduino PWM to analog with RC and OA and then use that voltage as a reference voltage for another OA...

Comment: To be clear, setting a voltage this precise can be very hard (also because this is in the range of noise). I'm not sure, if this even comes from the Arduino. It might as well come from the opamp circuit itself, since they are not build perfectly either. Depending on your exact circuit it might be better to use an extra circuit part for turning the opamp circuit really off, instead of letting it amplify noise.

Comment: @chrisl the 0.003V is from Arduino, of that i'm sure (tested it). it's just gonna count from 0V to 0.5V and then stay at 0.5V. can you please provide a link or anything related to that "extra circuit" you mentioned?

Comment: Where get's anything counted? I don't see something like this in your code. About the extra circuit: That was just a thought about cutting the power of the opamps (maybe through a MOSFET) or pulling the output of the opamp over a current limiting resistor to low (also with a MOSFET). Just a thought, not a full fletched circuit, that I could provide a link for

Comment: @chrisl i didn't add that counting to the code because it was unrelated to the question. using a mosfet/transistor is a good idea, i'll try that. thanks.

Comment: You probably won't get below 3mV even with a transistor (that's what the arduino already does). Do you really need to get below that tiny voltage, I mean, it's 4 times less than the pwm's (ideally filtered) resolution when running at 3V3. If so, the only chance I see is to use external circuitry

Comment: Inside the Arduino, a FET is turning on, shorting the output pin to the internal ground on the chip. If the ground of your external circuit is not at the same potential as the ground Inside the chip, your external circuit will see some voltage.  Now.... how could the two grounds be at different potentials?. Perhaps there is some current traveling through the wire connecting the two grounds! Make sure there is NO current in the wire that connects the grounds.

Comment: @Sim Son I suggested using a MOSFET after the amplification, because the problem seems, that the opamp amplifies the 3mV to an unwanted greater signal. Pulling the output of the amplification to a low voltage might be sufficient, so that the amplification itself doesn't matter at that point.

Comment: @newbie how did you actually test that those 3mV are comming from the arduino? Have any external circuitry been removed when you did so? Otherwise I would suspect those 3mV to be the opamp's input offset voltage.

Comment: @SimSon I disconnected everything form Arduino and then measured the voltage on pin 5.

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/what-exactly-gpio-pin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't output 0v because it's near impossible. 0.003v is in fact very low. The LOW output, according to the datasheet, can be as high as 0.8v (when powered by 5v) and still be considered valid.

LOW does not mean 0v. It means "below the voltage threshold that is considered a LOW".